# 11ty Site Working Locally, but Missing CSS and Bootstrap on GitHub Pages After Repository Restructure

Tags: html, css, github-pages, eleventy, static-site-generation

I have installed my 11ty, and all files are in the correct location (i think); when testing the page using the local server, the site is working well. However, the issue occurs when I push changes to the GitHub.

Below my files working tree:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrJSn.png)

I have uploaded my files using root for my GitHub Pages. But it comes with a 404 error. So, I have changed this to docs and altered my folder from  public to docs. This fixed some errors, and my site is now working. However, there are a few more errors I need help with.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6osg.png)

The main page is working now, but no CSS and Bootstrap are being added. All my njk files are also being ignored. There is just plain HTML.

I've been trying to change my files path, etc., but nothing works.

Here is also my eleventy.js config and link to my GitHub accout with all the files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgd5f.png)

https://github.com/aaamorek91/Portfolio.git

Any idea what this could be? Also, I don't know if the issue is related to my files or, rather, GitHub settings.

Many thanks!